# Finding a page holding a specific string/URL that is used in the content

Tags: database, search

In my situation do I want to find pages that have a URL in the content of the post that is redirecting to a 404 page doesn't exist. I want to able to search for this URL and find on which page(s) it is used using the best method.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a plugin that may be useful for finding broken links](https://wordpress.org/plugins/broken-link-checker/). It's called Broken Link Checker. From the description: "This WP plugin checks all URLs on your WordPress blog and gives you a complete report of the broken and redirected links."